# python regex for movie subtitles

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to make a simple regex that would recognize micro dvd format:

```
{52}{118}some text
{123}{202}some text
{203}{259}some text
{261}{309}some text
```

My code looks lke the following. `match_obj` is None and I don't know why:

```
import re
my_re = r"\{([0-9]*)\}\{[0-9]\}(.*)"
f = open('abc.txt')
match_obj = re.match(my_re, f.readline())
```

I have tried also:

```
match_obj = re.match(my_re, f.readline(), re.M|re.I)
```

with the same results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're very close - you're just missing a repeat symbol in the second number section. Your regex should look like this:

```
my_re = r"\{([0-9]*)\}\{[0-9]*\}(.*)"
```

Notice the added asterisk after the second `[]` block.

Answer (score 2):

```
\{([0-9]*)\}\{[0-9] \}(.*)
                  /|\
                   |
```

You're missing a repeater in your second number character class.

I'm not sure about the rules of movie subtitles, but I would assume the brackets can not be empty.

A stricter regex would then be (albeit, probably not needed in your case):

```
\{([0-9]+)\}\{[0-9]+\}(.*)
```

The `+` repeater means 1 or more. The `*` repeater means 0 or more.

- Are you only interested in the first number?
- Is the text meant to be optional?

Comment: This answer is a better answer than joonty's in that it asks a few valid questions and suggests further actions to be taken. Both answers are good though :)